# kernel warning disk error for command write - solaris svm

Tags: unix, hard-drive, solaris

Recently this warning came up on my message logs,

```
  scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@1c,600000/scsi@2/sd@0,0 (sd0):
  Oct 27 00:14:44 Error for Command: write(10)  Error Level:Retryable
  Oct 27 00:14:44 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.notice]         Requested Block: 101515828                 Error Block: 101515828
  Oct 27 00:14:44  scsi: [ID 107833 kern.notice]  Vendor: SEAGATE Serial Number: 0441B9B5H
  Oct 27 00:14:44 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.notice]         Sense Key: Hardware Error
  Oct 27 00:14:44 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.notice]         ASC: 0x19 (defect list error), ASCQ: 0x0, FRU: 0x2
```

This is showing signs of disk failing in my opinion. I have not seen the messages re-occurring. 
This is on a Solaris 9 Sparc system V240.
The disks are managed by SVM and "metadb" is showing the flags as "a"
Are there any tests or indications as to check/see if the disk is actually failing or was that error message initiated by something else.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root, you may run "format" and select the disk and then select "analyze"
followed by "read" test. 
You may also zero in on the disk area to test by selecting "setup" and setting the starting/ending block of the test around the Requested Block area. 
But in general it may be better to replace the disk.
Good Luck.